# How to code a light Jquery text loop

Tags: jquery, loops, text, scroll

I coded a jquery script that scrolls links inside a span when mouse pointer is over, and stops at mouseout.

http://jsfiddle.net/trustweb/Xvqfr/

This is a working solution but if you check CPU performances you notice how heavy it is.

Does exist a lighter solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xvqfr/14/ modified your fiddle and tested with 10% usage of CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reduce the timer interval (8ms) your performace would be better.
At the same time you should to avoid to use find method multiple times in the scrollText() method.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8sap/2/

Answer (score 0):

Cache result of selector  $elmt.find('.subcolumn-left-tab-title-slide a') into var to avoid frequent DOM traversal by selector

Answer (score 0):

First of all cache jQuery collections. No need to call `.find('.subcolumn-left-tab-title-slide a')` multiple times. Also setting styles with plain javascript like `style.left = left + 'px'` will improve performance as well.

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/Xvqfr/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xvqfr/15/ try
You can control speed by time, just remember that t=s/v, s = width(), v=number of pixels :) 
Have fun.